# Zend Paginator Limit Rows(Optimization)

Tags: zend-framework, zend-db, zend-db-table, zend-paginator

This is my query:

```
class services extends Zend_Db_Table{

 function Get_Services($user_id){
    $DB = Zend_Db_Table_Abstract::getDefaultAdapter();

    $select = $DB->select()
                ->from(array('p' => 'phone_service'))
                ->join(array('u' => 'user_preferences'), 'u.phone_service_id = p.phone_service_id')
                ->where('u.user_preferences_name = ?', 'is_user_package_active')
                ->where('p.user_id = ?', $user_id);
           return $select;
    }
  }
```

This is my controller:

```
class ServicesController extends Zend_Controller_Action{
       $instance = new services();
       $select = $instance->Get_Services($user_id);

       $adapter   = new Zend_Paginator_Adapter_DbSelect($select);
       $paginator = new Zend_Paginator($adapter);

       $page=$this->_getParam('page',1);
       $paginator->setItemCountPerPage(10);
       $paginator->setCurrentPageNumber($page);
       $paginator->setPagerange(5);
 }
```

What I am doing is that first I query all rows and then do this:

```
 $adapter   = new Zend_Paginator_Adapter_DbSelect($select);
 $paginator = new Zend_Paginator($adapter);
```

My question is, how can I optimize it so that it queries only 10 rows from the result and not all of them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With `DbSelect` adapter it *does* query only 10 rows. Profile your queries and inspect - you should see 2 selects AFAIR - one manipulated by ZF to obtain total count of rows and one to get the actual data with `LIMIT` and `OFFSET`.

Comment: but before that i am making query and than applying Zend_Paginator_Adapter_DbSelect does it matter ??

Comment: I don't see you making a query. You are creating a `Select` object, but it's only an object and no queries are made until you make them yourself via `fetchXxx()` methods or the paginator.